# Error while calling Sabre BargainFinderMax REST API — ERR.2SG.PROVIDER_TIMEOUT

Tags: sabre

I am getting occasional errors while calling Sabre BargainFinderMax REST API for the following request:

```
{  
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ":{  
        "OriginDestinationInformation":[  
            {  
                "DepartureDateTime":"2018-09-22T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation":{  
                    "LocationCode":"DEL"
                },
                "OriginLocation":{  
                    "LocationCode":"BOM"
                },
                "RPH":"0"
            },
            {  
                "DepartureDateTime":"2018-09-29T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation":{  
                    "LocationCode":"BOM"
                },
                "OriginLocation":{  
                    "LocationCode":"DEL"
                },
                "RPH":"1"
            }
        ],
        "TravelPreferences":{  
            "ValidInterlineTicket":true,
            "CabinPref":[  
                {  
                    "Cabin":"Y",
                    "PreferLevel":"Preferred"
                }
            ]
        },
        "POS":{  
            "Source":[  
                {  
                    "PseudoCityCode":"J6UJ",
                    "RequestorID":{  
                        "CompanyName":{  
                            "Code":"TN"
                        },
                        "ID":"REQ.ID",
                        "Type":"0.AAA.X"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions":{  
            "IntelliSellTransaction":{  
                "RequestType":{  
                    "Name":"50ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary":{  
            "AirTravelerAvail":[  
                {  
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity":[  
                        {  
                            "Code":"ADT",
                            "Quantity":1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "PriceRequestInformation":{  
                "CurrencyCode":"USD"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response with error code - ERR.2SG.PROVIDER_TIMEOUT

```
{  
    "status":"NotProcessed",
    "type":"Transport",
    "errorCode":"ERR.2SG.PROVIDER_TIMEOUT",
    "timeStamp":"2018-09-08T11:09:38.819-05:00",
    "message":"Connection error"
}
```

Response with error code - ERR.2SG.SEC.MISSING_CREDENTIALS

```
{  
    "status":"NotProcessed",
    "type":"Validation",
    "errorCode":"ERR.2SG.SEC.MISSING_CREDENTIALS",
    "timeStamp":"2018-09-08T11:26:06.919-05:00",
    "message":"Authentication data is missing"
}
```

Response with error code - WARN.RAF.APPLICATION

```
{  
    "status":"Complete",
    "reportingSystem":"RAF",
    "timeStamp":"2018-09-08T19:03:26+00:00",
    "type":"Application",
    "errorCode":"WARN.RAF.APPLICATION",
    "instance":"raf-darhlc006.sabre.com-8080",
    "message":"{\"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS\":{\"PricedItinCount\":0,\"BrandedOneWayItinCount\":0,\"SimpleOneWayItinCount\":0,\"DepartedItinCount\":0,\"SoldOutItinCount\":0,\"AvailableItinCount\":0,\"Version\":\"4.2.0\",\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Type\":\"SCHEDULES\",\"ShortText\":\"DSF server returned an error: unknown BRD airport=BOM\",\"Code\":\"PROCESS\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SCHEDULES\",\"ShortText\":\"DSF server returned an error: unknown OFF airport=BOM\",\"Code\":\"PROCESS\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"IF2\",\"ShortText\":\"No complete journey can be built in IF2/ADVJR1.\",\"Code\":\"PROCESS\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"WORKERTHREAD\",\"ShortText\":\"4220224579781953781\",\"Code\":\"TRANSACTIONID\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SERVER\",\"ShortText\":\"27033\",\"Code\":\"ASECT2LAPC00015.IDM.SGDCPROD.SABRE.COM\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"DRE\",\"ShortText\":\"21728\",\"Code\":\"RULEID\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"DEFAULT\",\"ShortText\":\"25238\",\"Code\":\"RULEID\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SCHEDULES\",\"ShortText\":\"NO FLIGHTS FOUND FOR BOM-DEL\",\"Code\":\"MSG\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SCHEDULES\",\"ShortText\":\"NO FLIGHTS FOUND FOR DEL-BOM\",\"Code\":\"MSG\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"SCHEDULES\",\"ShortText\":\"NO FLIGHT SCHEDULES FOR QUALIFIERS USED\",\"Code\":\"MSG\",\"MessageClass\":\"I\",\"content\":\"\"},{\"Type\":\"ERR\",\"ShortText\":\"Error during Processing\",\"Code\":\"ERR\",\"content\":\"\"}]}},\"Links\":[{\"rel\":\"self\",\"href\":\"https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.2.0/shop/flights?mode=live\"},{\"rel\":\"linkTemplate\",\"href\":\"https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com//shop/flights?mode=&limit=&offset=&enabletagging=\"}]}"
}
```

Response with no error

```
{  
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS":{  
        "PricedItinCount":50,
        "BrandedOneWayItinCount":0,
        "SimpleOneWayItinCount":0,
        "DepartedItinCount":0,
        "SoldOutItinCount":0,
        "AvailableItinCount":0,
        "Version":"4.2.0",
        "Success":{  

        },
        "Warnings":{...},
        "PricedItineraries":{...},
        "TPA_Extensions":{...}
    },
    "Links":[...]
}
```

The website is currently using Sabre Test Environment for the REST API calls.

What can be the reasons that the API returns with error codes like mentioned above sometimes?
Will moving to the production environment remove these kind of errors?

Any help to resolve the above issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While the Production environment will have significantly less errors, those errors can be found and you should consider them in your application.

- ERR.2SG.PROVIDER_TIMEOUT is a timeout response that can also happen in Production. It's much more common in testing environments.
- ERR.2SG.SEC.MISSING_CREDENTIALS can be avoided, it's that you are missing session details.
- WARN.RAF.APPLICATION means that there is a validation error or something in the request is invalid.